# get commits by single user in GIT

Tags: java, git

Is there anyway I can write the code to check the commits made by the user and show in list of currently logged in in my application using their email address? I am using Java Git API.

Comment: You should take a look [here](http://www.doublecloud.org/2013/01/how-to-read-git-repository-using-java-apis/). This is a basic tutorial to use git in Java.

Answer (score 0):

> ... check the commits made by the user

Passing  -c to the commit can overwrite any email you want

```
git commit -c user.email foo@foo.com ...
```

But if you want you can filter by author:

```
git log --author=<author>
```

Comment: I am using org.eclipse.egit.github. Can I pass a user email in this and list out all the commits made by the user of that email for particular repository?